# Add the "Featured" posts section in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, featured-tag

Can the *Featured* posts section be added to the Android app?

I think it would be a good option to make it available.

Comment: Do you mean questions with bounties?

Comment: Yes. Is that available?

Comment: No :( But you can search for `hasnotice:yes locked:no`; most of the results would be bountied questions.

Comment: OK I will try that.

Comment: Doesn't exist, now this very question serves as the feature request asking for it.