# How to see featured questions in the Stack Overflow app

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, android-app, bounties

How can you see featured questions, i.e., questions with bounties, in the Stack Overflow Android app?

Comment: I doubt if it exists: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258907/add-the-featured-posts-section-in-stack-exchange-android-app

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'Active' button on the top left; there, you can switch the view to Bounty mode:

[image]

Comment: is this the iOS app? I can't seem to find these options in the android app.

Comment: @VishnuVS ah, right. It's the iOS app; then, rene's link is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm always confused between all those version. Is this the Stack Overflow app or the SE app?

Comment: This screenshot is from the Stack Overflow iOS app.